# In $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod m$, does $n$ have to be an integer?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, real-numbers, integers

> In $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod m$, does $n$ have to be an integer?

I just came upon this rule and am wondering its limits. Thank you

Comment: No, $4^{1/2} \equiv 16^{1/2} (\mod{2})$

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question means. It's certainly possible to write the above for non-integers $n$, in certain circumstances, but, in general, when you see this notation, it is usually correct, if not otherwise stated, to assume that it is meant that $n$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $a^n$ and $b^n$ are integers, there is nothing new.

I don't think that anything forbids to extend the definition of the modulo to non-integer numbers and say

$$a\equiv b\mod m\iff \frac{a-b}m\in\mathbb Z.$$

Then,

$$2^{1/3}\equiv(15\sqrt[3]4+75\sqrt[3]2+127)^{1/3}\mod 5,$$
$$2^\pi\equiv \left((2^\pi+3e)^{1/\pi}\right)^\pi\mod e.$$

Answer (score 0):

Usually in equations of the form $a^n \equiv_m b^n$, the $n$ is an integer. In general it is not well defined if $n$ is not an integer. If for example you take $n=\frac{1}{2}$ then for all odd prime $m$, an element $a$ will either have 2 roots, so that $a^{1/2}$ is two elements, or that $a$ has no roots at all.

For example, for $m=3$ you get that $1^{1/2}\equiv_3 1,2$ while there is no root for $2$ and $0^{1/2}\equiv_3 0$. This is why this is not a standard notation.

EDIT: I assumed here that you meant that $m,a,b$ are integers, though of course this mustn't be the case.

Comment: Of course, it isn't always defined when $n$ is a negative integer, either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are correct. Though in this case, if $m$ is prime then it is well defined whenever you don't take the inverse of zero.

Comment: True, but nowhere was it said that $n$ is prime. And when writing about congruences, of course, you mean "whenever you don't take the inverse of a number divisible by $n$." But the real problem is that congruence notation is about integers, not about the related modular ring. So $a^{-1}$ i dangerously bad notation. It makes sense in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for some elements, but the point of modular notation is to stay in the integers, so using the notation there is confusing and risky.

Answer (score 0):

What’s necessary is that exponentiation, $a^n$, must be well-defined for the values of $a$ and $n$, each in a specified domain; and the relation $a\equiv_m b$ must be well-defined within the range of values of the exponentiation. Here’s a relatively obscure example:

If $a$ is a principal unit in a $p$-adic domain such as $\Bbb Z_p$, that is $a\equiv_{\,p}\!1$, then if $z$ is any $p$-adic integer (in $\Bbb Z_p$, but need not  be rational), $a^z$ is well-defined, using completeness of $\Bbb Z_p$. So it’s perfectly grammatical to write $a^z\equiv_{p^m}b^z$.